# JMeter: JMeter execution stops after sending request using TCP Sampler

Tags: tcp, server, jmeter

Using TCP Sampler, I am sending some text which needs to be returned in Response and what I can see is Request is getting send but there is Server Error and JMeter execution stops.

TCP Server is running, it does receive request from JMeter but there is problem receiving reponse from Server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if there is any configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

The communication is that JMeter sends the request and hopes to get the answer through the same port. Are the ports identical?

Comment: No, the ports are not identical but different Ports for Send and Receive.

Comment: Try to configure server ports to give the answer through the same port and check if the error still exists.